# The pipe 'xxx' could not be found (

Tags: angular6

I am trying to add search to Angular 6. Always it throws the following error:
I tried with my custom pipes and from third parties downloaded in NPMJS, but the error is always the same.

What can I do?

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'searchByName' could not be found ("

              <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let [ERROR ->]item of catalogStore.catalog | async | searchByName:searchTerm">
                      <!-- <li *ngFo"): ng:///ProductsModule/ProductsViewComponent.html@8:34
```

Comment: Have you included the pipe in your declarations in either the app.module or shared.module if you are using a shared.module?

Comment: Sure. Anyway, ng puts it automatically, but I chcked and it is exists

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a different way.

Instead of using filters I added something like:

```
<div *ngIf="item.title.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0>
```

And thats solved my problem!!